# C realloc 2D char array

Tags: c, arrays, char, 2d

I want load char from file to 2D array. But I don't know length of separate lines (1 line (1 word) per 1 row in array). So I allocated 1*char* array and then counted chars in 1 line and allocated them. Then I wanted to `realloc` (2*char*) array so it can handle 2 lines. Here, in second turn, it always crashes (line `patterns=realloc(patterns, sizeof(*patterns)*patternCounter);` ). I know the code isn't perfect (I don't control error and so on), but I don't think it would help. Now it doesn't work either.

NOTE: first argument of function hasn't been used yet

input file (1 word per line, end line '\n', so last line is empty)

```
woman
man
meat
animal
anim
```

My code

```
void failure(state *automaton, FILE *fpattern){

    int patternCounter=0, charCounter=0, i;
    char c;
    char **patterns=NULL;

    rewind(fpattern);

    while((c=fgetc(fpattern))!=EOF){
        charCounter++;

        if(c=='\n') {
            patternCounter++;
            patterns=realloc(patterns, sizeof(*patterns)*patternCounter);

            fseek(fpattern, -charCounter, SEEK_CUR);

            for (i = 0; i < charCounter; i++) {
                patterns[i]=malloc(1);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < charCounter-1; i++) {
                patterns[patternCounter-1][i]=(char)fgetc(fpattern);
            }

            patterns[patternCounter-1][i]='\0';

            fgetc(fpattern);

            charCounter=0;

            printf("%s\n", patterns[patternCounter-1]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < patternCounter; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", patterns[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't understand what is wrong. Debugging didn't help.

Comment: The line `patterns[patternCounter-1][i]=(char)fgetc(fpattern);` should cause buffer overrun since only 1 byte is allocated to `patterns[patternCounter-1]`. Also, throwing previously read data away is very bad idea.

Comment: Fmmm, actually `patterns[patternCounter-1]` may be uninitialized.

Comment: Is there a maximum length for you words? It would make things easier for you, because allocating array byte by byte is not that great...

Comment: No. I don't know the length

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.  `char c` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing away previously allocated buffer and allocate only 1 element, then trying to save too many characters there, which are very bad things.

Try changing

```
for (i = 0; i < charCounter; i++) {
    patterns[i]=malloc(1);
}
```

to

```
patterns[patternCounter-1]=malloc(charCounter);
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. Thanks so much. Such bad bug, don't know why I didn't figure it out.